What are the properties of the incidence matrcies of undirected graphs
Here is the definition of incidence matrix I find on Wikipedia
https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Incidence_matrix
Suppose we have a graph $G$ with $N$ nodes and $e$ edges (we only consider undirected graphs here).
From the definition, the incidence matrix $B$ is of dimension $N\cdot e$.
Here we assume $N=e$ to discuss the eigenvalues of $B$.
My question is what are some generic properties of the eigenvalues of incidence matrix $B$?
For example, I am considering whether the incidence matrix of an undirected graph has all positive eigenvalues.
This intuition comes from the fact that the graph Laplacian can $L$ be represented as $L = B B^T$ and we know that $L$ has all positive eigenvalues.
Thanks!

It's not a particularly natural thing to do to take the eigenvalues of an incidence matrix; generally the eigenvalues are only meaningful for a matrix which maps a vector space to itself, but the incidence matrix maps between two different vector spaces even if it happens to be the case that $N = e$. And no, there's no reason the incidence matrix should have all positive eigenvalues, and you should be able to come up with a counterexample yourself.

To restate Qiaochu's objection in concrete terms: the incidence matrix depends on what order you write down the vertices and edges.  Eigenvalues are not preserved by this reordering, so what exactly do you mean "the" eigenvalues of "the" incidence matrix?  It's really more like a family of possible eigenvalues of $n!$ possible presentations of the incidence matrix.

Thank you for your comments. I wanted to use the incidence matrix as a discrete gradient operator and study its eigenvalue properties. May I ask what other matrices can be interpreted as a discrete gradient operator AND possible to study its eigenvalue properties? For example, can the adjacency matrix be viewed as a discrete gradient operator? If not, what is the generic methodology to find one?
